# How to show data on form in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

```
   I am getting details from an api which is an array of object.

    (function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp.components')
        .directive('abc', abc);

    abc.$inject = ['$http', '$timeout', 'ApiServices'];

    function abc($http, $timeout, ApiServices) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {},
            link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
                $('#bankMaster').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
                    scope.list=[];
                });
                $('#bankMaster').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                    scope.list=[];

                    scope.getAllDetails = function () {
                        ApiServices.getAllDetails().then(
                            function (response) {
                                scope.list = response.data;
                            },
                            function (err) {
                                // Handle error here
                                console.log('Error' + JSON.stringify(err.data));
                            });
                    };
            },
            templateUrl: 'js/folder/abc.html'
        };
    }

})();
```

I am trying to show this data on front end:-

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="abcForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>User Type :</label>
                    <label>{{list[0].userType}}</label>
                <label>User Code :</label>
                    <label>{{list[0].userCode}}</label>
                <label>Cost Price :</label>
                    <label>{{list[0].costPrice}}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Purchase Date :</label>
                    <label>{{list[0].date}}</label>
                <label>Taxes :</label>
                    <label>{{list[0].taxes}}</label>
                <label>Other  :  {{list[0].other}}</label>
            </div>
</form>
```

But nothing getting displayed.My syntax is correct but I think I am making some other mistake which I am not able to understand.Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this code?

My Apiservices Code:-

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp.core')
        .factory('ApiServices', ApiServices);

    /* @ngInject */
    function ApiServices($q, $rootScope, $http) {
        return {
           getAllDetails: getAllDetails
        };
           function getAllDetails() {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/abc/data/'
            });
        }



    };
})();
```

Comment: ca n u provide some mock data of response.data

Comment: Where is abc directive on your html?

Comment: please provide code for ApiServices

Comment: ApiServices code added

Comment: where are you using the directive tag in your html?...better attach your fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the `'myApp.core'` module in main module `'myApp.components'` like below
    `angular.module('myApp.components', ['myApp.core'])`
and make sure `'myApp.core'` module is loaded first.
Let me know if you still have any other issues

Comment: I don't think that is an issue because I am using Apiservices in other directives too and showing data on respective htmls, thats working fine.

Comment: you should not down vote the answer if you are not confident at all. I am very much sure that the module should be injected into the main module to use it in its directives and controllers. remove that down vote and learn angular first. firstly you should post the error message as well here.

 'angular.module('myApp.components')' and 'ApiServices' does not have any relation between, so how can the directive 'abc' will be aware of

Comment: 'ApiServices'. check the other services how there are written.

Comment: check this link when an answer should be down voted
https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: if you unnecessarily down vote like this with out having any knowledge, nobody will post answers to your questions

Comment: I didn't down vote your answer as I don't have right .